# using Cucumber with Netzke to call an action in Grid Panel

Tags: cucumber, netzke

I'm working on Rails(3.1.3) with Netzke(0.7.3).

I very new for Cucumber.

```rb
add_account_for_user.feature

Feature: Add Account For User Feature
In order to add login account
As an Administrator
I want to add login account for other role

Scenario: Adding Login Account
  When I login as an Administrator
  Then I should be on admin page

  When I click on 'Administration' button at right upper of page
  Then I should see 'Administrator Management'
  And I should see 'Add' button in Administrator Management toolbar

  When I click on 'Add' button
  Then I wait 10 seconds # for check what happen
```

The problem is at `When I click on 'Add' button` step. 
It pass but not working correctly. (It should fire event `onAddInForm`)
It's hanging in loading and do not show new windows panel.

```rb
my_steps.rb

Then /^(?:|I )click on '(\w*)'(?:|.*)$/ do |label|
  click_link_or_button(label)
  step "wait for the response from sever"
end

When /^(?:|I )wait for (?:.*)$/ do
  page.driver.browser.execute_script(<<-JS)
  JS
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Found the solution!!***

The solution is try to collect Component that you use. and then call that action directly.

```
When /I press 'Add' button in the '(\w*)' grid$/ do |grid_name|
  page.driver.browser.execute_script <<-JS
    var containerComp = Ext.getCmp("main_container");   
    var grid = containerComp.down("#"+"#{grid_name.underscore}_grid");
    grid.onAddInForm();
  JS
end
```

But I still don't understand why it not call `onAddInForm` after click.